# Database serialization error when editing paragraphs

Tags: upgrading, 9

I'm upgrading my sites to Drupal 9. I'm only seeing one issue after the update when clicking "Edit" on a Paragraph on one of my pages:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /node/691/edit?ajax_form=1
StatusText: error
ResponseText: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.LogicException: The database connection is not serializable. This probably means you are serializing an object that has an indirect reference to the database connection. Adjust your code so that is not necessary. Alternatively, look at DependencySerializationTrait as a temporary solution. in Drupal\Core\Database\Connection-&gt;__sleep() (line 1826 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Connection.php). serialize(Array) (Line: 14)
Drupal\Component\Serialization\PhpSerialize::encode(Array) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Core\KeyValueStore\DatabaseStorageExpirable-&gt;doSetWithExpire(&#039;form-GeirjRgkOxybCxOKd8UyfCEMS1nxWYErh2e5RxEI8Z0&#039;, Array, 21600) (Line: 122)
Drupal\Core\KeyValueStore\DatabaseStorageExpirable-&gt;setWithExpire(&#039;form-GeirjRgkOxybCxOKd8UyfCEMS1nxWYErh2e5RxEI8Z0&#039;, Array, 21600) (Line: 193)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormCache-&gt;setCache(&#039;form-GeirjRgkOxybCxOKd8UyfCEMS1nxWYErh2e5RxEI8Z0&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 459)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;setCache(&#039;form-GeirjRgkOxybCxOKd8UyfCEMS1nxWYErh2e5RxEI8Z0&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;rebuildForm(&#039;node_landing_page_edit_form&#039;, Object, Array) (Line: 629)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;processForm(&#039;node_landing_page_edit_form&#039;, Array, Object) (Line: 321)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder-&gt;buildForm(Object, Object) (Line: 73)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController-&gt;getContentResult(Object, Object) (Line: 39)
Drupal\layout_builder\Controller\LayoutBuilderHtmlEntityFormController-&gt;getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer-&gt;executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber-&gt;Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 158)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 91)
Drupal\shield\ShieldMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel-&gt;handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 706)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel-&gt;handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

I'm at a loss as to where to look to solve this issue.

Where is this breaking?

Edit:

Drupal 9.1.0
Paragraphs 8.x-1.12

Applied database updates and cleared cache post-update but this did not resolve the issue.

Could not reproduce in a fresh installation.

All multi-sites in this Drupal installation are affected by this bug. Since it wasn't reproduce-able on a fresh installation of Core 9.1.0 and using Paragraphs would it be a safe assumption that either a custom or contrib module somewhere is doing something that is causing this?

Aside from disabling modules one-by-one I'm not sure what I should look for here. Thank you!

Comment: Drupal 9, okay. But what D9 version exactly, what Paragraphs version exactly, in what exact environment? Have you searched the [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/paragraphs?categories=All)? Can this be reproduced in a fresh installation? What are the steps to reproduce it? Did you clear cache and run database updates after upgrading? Please, edit your post and add more info that helps us decide if this is a bug which must be reported to the module's issue queue, or if this can be easily fixed via some config or something else. Many thanks 

Comment: @leymannx Sorry for the lack of detail. I've gathered some more specifics and did some testing and edited my original post.

Comment: Also encountering this problem, though on Drupal 8.8

Comment: @plambre I forgot to follow up here. Do you have the Serialize module enabled? I believe that was the cause of this issue on my site

Comment: Having it enabled or disabled was the problem?

Comment: @plambre Enabled, once we disabled it everything worked normally.